# Directory replication in New server

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

Scenario is to replicate all the directories,sub-directories,files,symbolic links present in Linux  development Server to Linux QA Server.

Lot of unix users also to be created.

Consider an unix user - `edwprod` , there are lot of sub-directories and soft link present inside this folder `/home/edwprod/`.

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 edwprod  edwprod     0 Jan 25 13:23 ksh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 edwprod  edwprod    32 Jan 30 06:30 output -> /apps/application_scripts/output
lrwxrwxrwx 1 edwprod  edwprod    30 Jan 30 07:02 wp37 -> /apps/application_scripts/wp37
lrwxrwxrwx 1 edwprod  edwprod    32 Jan 31 05:57 in_dir -> /apps/application_scripts/in_dir
lrwxrwxrwx 1 edwprod  edwprod    30 Jan 31 10:57 SVEN -> /apps/application_scripts/SVEN
drwxrwxrwx 6 edwprod  edwprod  1024 Feb  1 08:45 bin
```

This is how the directory looks like. All the directories reside inside folder `/apps/application_scripts/`.

Both the directory tree should be replicated in Linux QA Server without affecting the symbolic links. Let me know the best possible way to do it?

Comment: I indented your code. Not sure, what the last line `/home/edwprod>` after the output of `ls` means.

Comment: when u replicate the directories in new server , symbolic links , files get crashed and become invalid.

Answer (score 1):

`rsync -e ssh -aHS $SOURCEDIR/ $TARGET:$TARGETDIR/`

Use `useradd` with the original data (uid, gid, encrypted pw, ...) to recreate the user on the target system.